# how get data from website database using URL

Tags: database, web

I have website and I know all it's files and it's database and I want to get some data from this website using it's url 
where I but my query and how I can apply this query 
thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to answer with this little information. Do you want to access the database from the web server, or from a remote computer?

--local: access as usual, with any DB manager

--remote: this is difficult and depends on the kind of server

If you want to create a web page to show the content of the database, maybe you should take a look at DJANGO and see whether it fits you.  And if you want to execute queries and obtain the result, maybe a basic PHP form is enough.

Anyway, please provide more information to obtain concrete answers.

Best regards

Comment: I want to access database from the web server

Comment: I am not admin in this site and I want some data from it's database and I know it's database and it's php file

Comment: if you are not the admin, then you cannot access the database from outside the web server